# Сворачивать FloatActionMenu при открытии Activity

Tags: android

Есть такое `FloatActionMenu` с кнопками. Как сворачивать `FloatActionMenu` при открытии `Activity`?

```
<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/fabMain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        style="@style/MenuButtonsStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic1"
        app:fab_label="@string/text1"
        fab:fab_label="@string/text1"
        fab:fab_size="mini"/>

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        style="@style/MenuButtonsStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic2"
        app:fab_label="@string/text2"
        fab:fab_label="@string/text2"
        fab:fab_size="mini"/>

</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
```

Comment: А что вы пробовали? Может стоит хотя бы посмотреть исходники указанной вами библиотеки https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/clans/fab/FloatingActionMenu.java? Кстати, там есть публичные методы `public void toggle(boolean animate)`, `public void open(final boolean animate)` и `public void close(final boolean animate)`

Comment: помогло. спасибо